# Eslint rule to enforce empty lines in between Vue script keys

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, eslint

Is there an eslint rule that will enforce empty lines in between keys within the exported object of the script tag in a `.vue` file? I'm looking for something like this to be accepted:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Item,
    ItemListNav,
    LazyWrapper
  },

  validate({ params: { feed } }) {
    return validFeeds.includes(feed)
  },

  data() {
    return {
      transition: 'slide-right',
      displayedPage: Number(this.page) || 1
    }
  }
}
```

As opposed to this one throwing an error:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Item,
    ItemListNav,
    LazyWrapper
  }, // No empty line here 
  validate({ params: { feed } }) {
    return validFeeds.includes(feed)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      transition: 'slide-right',
      displayedPage: Number(this.page) || 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brady, I just wrote a custom ESLint rule that does this. Are you still intereseted? Edit: Wow to the day two years later... funny!

Comment: Oh amazing! I actually don't currently need it (sadly I'm now working on React instead) but if you could submit an answer with a link to the custom rule you created and some instructions/code then I can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Just FYI I will try to submit it to the eslint-vue repository first, or at least adhere to their coding standard.

Comment: Update: I finally opened an [Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/pull/1818) and [Pull Request](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1817).